# Не могу получить доступ к полю одной из структур WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, структуры

Есть код работы со структурой SYSTEM_INFO из WinAPI:

```
#include <sysinfoapi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    cout << si.DUMMYUNIONNAME.DUMMYSTRUCTNAME.wProcessorArchitecture;

    return 0;
}
```

Определение структуры:

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
    __C89_NAMELESS union {
        DWORD dwOemId;
        __C89_NAMELESS struct {
            WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
            WORD wReserved;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
    DWORD dwPageSize;
    LPVOID lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    LPVOID lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
    DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
    DWORD dwNumberOfProcessors;
    DWORD dwProcessorType;
    DWORD dwAllocationGranularity;
    WORD wProcessorLevel;
    WORD wProcessorRevision;
} SYSTEM_INFO, *LPSYSTEM_INFO;
```

Вроде, всё нормально, однако, для строки с выводом выскакивает ошибка "expected unqualified-id before '.' token". Кроме того, при попытке обращения к полям объекта DUMMYSTRUCTNAME система автозаполнения не предлагает мне варианты "wProcessorArchitecture" и "wReserved", вместо этого она предлагает "DUMMYSTRUCTNAME" и "dwOemId". И так до бесконечности.

Comment: `cout << si.wProcessorArchitecture;`

Comment: Спасибо. А можно узнать, почему так?

Comment: Есть понятие "безимянные" юнионы (и структуры). Если имени нету - то обращение напрямую. http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-_system_info *An obsolete member that is retained for compatibility. Applications should use the wProcessorArchitecture branch of the union.* перевод - оставлено для совместимости, используйте wProcessorArchitecture напрямую.